# Can I divide 3kV pulses with a voltage divider?

Tags: voltage-divider, high-voltage, high-frequency

The pulses are generated with a high voltage push/pull switch that outputs high voltage pulses at the voltages it being fed by a DC high voltage power supply and the signal is controlled by its TTL input. The generated high voltage pulses have picosecond level rise time.

Such pulser has one output and is rather expensive. Now I need 2 synced pulses at 3000V and 2400V. It would be problematic and expensive if I use 2 such pulsers. Is it possible that I use a voltage dividing device to create 2 pulses from 1 3000V pulse with sub microsecond rise time? In addition, the voltage divider needs to have high impedance so that it doesn't consume a huge amount of power.

The divided pulses will have no load, since they are meant to create electric potential difference inside a vacuum system. Sometimes the ion beam would hit the electrode and create a small current (sub-μA level), and in this case the load can be regard as a minuscule capacitor.

I have tried to divide the voltage of TTL pulse using metal oxide resistors, the output wasn't great. The rise time to 200 mV was longer than 10μs. At first I thought it was the large parasitic inductance of the potentiometer, but after I changed it to a fixed resistor the problem remains.

Comment: @Yibo Do you want both HV pulsers to be triggered at the same moment? Or is there some reason one is to be triggered from the result of the other one being triggered?

Comment: @jonk I want them to be triggered at the same time.

Comment: @Yibo I'm no expert on picosecond risetimes and I'm not sure if you need it or just happen to have it laying about. But I'm not yet sure why your mind went to taking the response of one system to drive another when you might otherwise ask about using a T to leverage the existing output to drive both systems. I must be really missing something.

Comment: @jonk I'm not sure what you mean by two systems... I currently only have one HV pulser, and my question is either there is way that I can divide its output to two different electric potentials or I have to buy another HV pulser to meet my need.

Comment: @Yibo My misunderstanding. I completely follow, now. So yes. Another way to achieve it would be with a series of NE-2 bulbs, or similar. How tightly do you need to arrange the voltage?